# How to install a program in linux for all users not only for root?

Tags: linux

I installed the shrewsoft vpnmanger on my linux (crunchbang kernel 3.2.0-4 amd64) the problem is, that somehow it can only be started as sudo. Can someone explain how i can fix this?

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/iked&
```

How can I change the iked installation so that it is available for each user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's just about the paths a normal user's shell search for commands. But normally it makes sense that those commands located in a `sbin` dir are not accessible by typing just the command's name. Those commands need access to protected resources that are only accessible by `root`.

But if you have the luck that you can gain the full rights by means of `sudo` you can simply create an alias via

```
 alias iked="sudo /usr/local/sbin/iked"
```

and add it into your shell's resource file.

To make the full command accessible to all users by simply typing `iked` you can create a little bash script named `iked` with content

```
 #!/bin/bash
 sudo /usr/local/sbin/iked
```

and place it in `/usr/local/bin`.

Of course that implies an appropriate `/etc/sudoers` file and that the execute permission of `iked` is set.

Comment: Also, your users could add `/usr/local/bin/` to their `PATH`.... and you could edit it system-wide in e.g. `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` etc...

Answer (score 1):

try copying or symlinking in it in /usr/bin.

and see if it work for the user then, if it has a global log file (I don't know about this app so not one to comment) but assuming it has some log in /var/log/iked.log and its been written by root you will have permssion issues by another user, so chown it to some neutral group like users or something.:

[Try here](http://vouters.dyndns.org/tima/Linux-Shrew_VPN_Client-Installing_and_using_Shrew_VPN_client_on_Linux.html) it may give you more info, I can see you could try:

/usr/bin/iked -d 4

But from what I read it does have a log in /var/log and yep that permission issue would be the primary issue specially if root was the first user to run this app.